# Groupy Pandas dataframe by multiple columns to find percentage change from previous month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group by multiple columns and find a percent change from the previous month

```
Company   Prod     Month-Year    Counts
 Comp A   gold      2019-05       20
 Comp A   gold      2019-04       5
 Comp A   gold      2019-03       10
 Comp B   silver    2019-06       18
 Comp B   silver    2019-05       36
 Comp B   silver    2019-04       50
 Comp C   black     2019-07       100
 Comp C   black     2019-06       50
 Comp C   black     2019-05       5
 Comp C   black     2019-04       2
```

I have tried:

```
df.groupby(['Company','Prod','Month-Year'])['Counts'].pct_change() + 1
```

but I end up getting all nans

```
df.groupby(['Company'])['Counts'].pct_change() + 1
```

when I try the above it doesn't give me the correct % changes, it gives the the percentage change from the first record within the company and prod groupby.

Desired output:

```
Company   Prod     Month-Year    Counts  %-Change
 Comp A   gold      2019-05       20       400%
 Comp A   gold      2019-04       5        -50%
 Comp A   gold      2019-03       10        -
 Comp B   silver    2019-06       18       -50%
 Comp B   silver    2019-05       36       -28%
 Comp B   silver    2019-04       50        -
 Comp C   black     2019-07       100       100%
 Comp C   black     2019-06       50        900%
 Comp C   black     2019-05       5         150%
 Comp C   black     2019-04       2         -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, make sure your df is sorted properly (by company and Month year):

```
df.sort_values(by=['Company','Month-Year'], inplace=True)
```

second, you can use lambda and apply such that:

```
df['%-Change']=df.groupby(['Company'])['Counts'].apply(lambda x: x/x.shift(1)-1).fillna(0)*100
```

Lastly, if you wish to sort it as presented in your question:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Company','Month-Year'],  ascending=[True, False])
```

desired result:

[image]

Note: you can group by (['Company']) or (['Company', 'Prod']) (depends on the request)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
df['pct']=df.sort_values('Month-Year').groupby(['Company','Prod'])['Counts'].pct_change()+1
```

Comment: In your answer the result will ignore each 'company','prod' and it will make the percentage based on previous row. See my screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/R5TS7oi.png